# Porting libmfcc to C# using Bass Library

Tags: c#, signal-processing, fft, spectrum, mfcc

I am currently using The Bass Library for Audio Analysis which can calculate FFT and return it as an Array, libmfcc uses this Data to calculate the Value of the MFCC Coefficients which I need. (Info: MFCC is like a Audio Spectrum but it fits more the way how the Human Hearing and Frequency Scaling works)
The Bass Library returns Values from 0 to 1 as FFT Values.

Now I encountered several Problems and Questions:

- Their FFT Example Data seems to have a different Format, Values are very high and the total of the 8192 FFT Values Sum to 10739.24 , how can that be?[/li]
- In their [example Application](http://code.google.com/p/libmfcc/source/browse/libmfcc_example/example.c) they call the Function like the following. Why they Use 128 as FFT Array Size if they just loaded 8192 Values?
- Using their MFCC Class which I copied and edited a bit to match C# Syntax/Functions I get negative Values for some Coefficients, I dont think that should be the case.

Can anyone help me out why it is returning negative Values or what I did wrong ?
I made a simple example Ready to Try Program which does the described above and is useful for debugging.

Link: http://www.xup.in/dl,17603935/MFCC_Test.rar/

Output from my C# Application (Most likely not correct)

> Coeff 16 = 0,017919318626506 Coeff 17 = -0,155580763009355 Coeff 18 =
>   -0,76072865841987 Coeff 19 = 0,108961510335727 Coeff 20 = 0,819025783804398 Coeff 21 = -0,660508603974514 Coeff 22 =
>   -0,951623924906163 Coeff 23 = 0,424922129906254 Coeff 24 = 0,0129727009313168 Coeff 25 = -0,388796833267654 Coeff 26 =
>   0,270839393161931 Coeff 27 = -0,138515788828431 Coeff 28 =
>   -0,454837674981149 Coeff 29 = -0,448629344922371 Coeff 30 = -0,11908663618393 Coeff 31 = 0,237500036702818 Coeff 32 = 0,114874386870208 Coeff 33 = -0,100822381384326 Coeff 34 =
>   0,144242143551012 Coeff 35 = 0,209338502838453 Coeff 36 =
>   0,247588420953066 Coeff 37 = -0,451654204112441 Coeff 38 =
>   0,0346927542067229 Coeff 39 = 0,180816031061584

Their example FFT Data (Different Format?)

> 14.524506
>   38.176063
>   10.673860
>   3.705076
>   2.102398
>   1.461585
>   1.145616
>   0.974108
>   0.878079
>   0.825304
>   0.798959
>   0.789067
>   0.789914
>   0.797102
>   0.808576
>   0.822048
>   0.836592
>   0.851101
>   0.864869
>   0.877625
>   0.888780
>   0.897852
>   0.905033
>   0.910054
>   0.912214
>   0.912414
>   0.909593
>   0.904497

Answer (score 0):

I can answer the first part:
   The sample code clearly states that the input data was computed using [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/), which produces an [unnormalized result](http://www.fftw.org/fftw2_doc/fftw_3.html#SEC23).  You need to divide by sqrt(n) to get the normalized values, which is what I suspect BASS returns.

Perhaps multiplying your inputs by sqrt(n) will give you better results.

Comment: Thanks for your Interest if you mean the Size of Values returned from Bass,I tried it and Im still getting negative Values.
I did it like this, I believe its correct: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=pSgTMt19

Comment: I just compiled their example on Ubuntu with the Original C Code, however it still returns negative Values, I dont think that in MFCC negative Values are outputted usually ?

Comment: Sorry for repost, I just noticed they Input 8192 FFT Bins in the example and set the binSize Parameter to 128 then, is this a Typo or could there be a Reason behind it?

Answer (score 0):

The MFCC routine returns cepstral coefficients (DCT of the log of mel magnitudes), *not* mel magnitude values. Cepstral coefficients can be negative. I believe the value 128 in the example code is indeed a mistake by the author. In order to preserve the signal energy an FFT requires normalization at some point (either after FFT, iFFT or split between the two). In the example you're looking at the raw (unnormalized) magnitudes, which is why they are so large.